# Merge multiple data frames in different list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I want to merge one df, with multiple logical vector. here's an example of what I want:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c(1.1, 5.4, 9.3, 6.1 ,4.5)
df <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
list1 <- list(df, df1, df2)
```

In my data, `df1` and `df2` are different than `df` but it's easier.
I have my logical vector and I want to cbind them with the first df of the first list.

```
vc <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE,FALSE)
vc1 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
vc2 <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
list2 <- list(vc, vc1, vc2)
```

I know how to do it one at a time.

```
list2[[1]] <- cbind(vc, df)
list2[[2]] <- cbind(vc1, df)
list2[[3]] <- cbind(vc2, df)
```

So the final result will be:

```
list2
[[1]]
     vc a   b
1  TRUE 1 1.1
2 FALSE 2 5.4
3  TRUE 3 9.3
4  TRUE 4 6.1
5 FALSE 5 4.5

[[2]]
    vc1 a   b
1 FALSE 1 1.1
2 FALSE 2 5.4
3  TRUE 3 9.3
4  TRUE 4 6.1
5 FALSE 5 4.5

[[3]]
   vc2 a   b
1 TRUE 1 1.1
2 TRUE 2 5.4
3 TRUE 3 9.3
4 TRUE 4 6.1
5 TRUE 5 4.5
```

But I really have a lot of data and it will take me "years" to do it.

Comment: `list2 = lapply(list2, cbind, df)` is equivalent to your "I know how to do it one at a time" code. Not really sure how you want the rest of `list1` to be used... Do you want `cbind(vc, df)`, `cbind(vc1, df1)`, `cbind(vc2, df2)`? In that case, `Map(cbind, list2, list1)`

Comment: Why have three dfs and only use df?

Comment: Because I have multiple ```df ```(df1, df2, df3.....). I would like to do the same thing as I do with ```df``` and ```vc, vc1, vc2``` .  And I have multiple logical vector for each ```df```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `bind_cols` and `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(list2, ~ bind_cols(l = .x, df))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lapply here :

```r
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b <- c(1.1, 5.4, 9.3, 6.1 ,4.5)
df <- data.frame(a,b)

vc <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE,FALSE)
vc1 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
vc2 <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
list2 <- list(vc, vc1, vc2)

lapply(list2, function(l) cbind(l, df))
#> [[1]]
#>       l a   b
#> 1  TRUE 1 1.1
#> 2 FALSE 2 5.4
#> 3  TRUE 3 9.3
#> 4  TRUE 4 6.1
#> 5 FALSE 5 4.5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>       l a   b
#> 1 FALSE 1 1.1
#> 2 FALSE 2 5.4
#> 3  TRUE 3 9.3
#> 4  TRUE 4 6.1
#> 5 FALSE 5 4.5
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      l a   b
#> 1 TRUE 1 1.1
#> 2 TRUE 2 5.4
#> 3 TRUE 3 9.3
#> 4 TRUE 4 6.1
#> 5 TRUE 5 4.5
```

Answer (score 2):

*If you intended to use all objects you provided:* Put vectors and data frames into lists and `cbind` them one by one using `Map`.

```
Map(cbind, vc=list(vc, vc1, vc2), list(df, df1, df2))
# [[1]]
#      vc a   b
# 1  TRUE 1 1.1
# 2 FALSE 2 5.4
# 3  TRUE 3 9.3
# 4  TRUE 4 6.1
# 5 FALSE 5 4.5
# 
# [[2]]
#      vc a   b
# 1 FALSE 1 1.1
# 2 FALSE 2 5.4
# 3  TRUE 3 9.3
# 4  TRUE 4 6.1
# 5 FALSE 5 4.5
# 
# [[3]]
#     vc a   b
# 1 TRUE 1 1.1
# 2 TRUE 2 5.4
# 3 TRUE 3 9.3
# 4 TRUE 4 6.1
# 5 TRUE 5 4.5
```